# x11vnc auto-start not working after Upgrading to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, vnc, systemd

x11vnc was working fine in 15.10, but after upgrading it doesn't work on startup

Trying to manually run from terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/:0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**works fine!!**

but when using with `sudo` it doesn't:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/:0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
 --- x11vnc loop: 1 ---

 --- x11vnc loop: waiting for: 12140

25/04/2016 10:36:39 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbauth
25/04/2016 10:36:39 passing arg to libvncserver: /home/user/.vnc/passwd
25/04/2016 10:36:39 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
25/04/2016 10:36:39 passing arg to libvncserver: 5900
25/04/2016 10:36:39 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 12140
No protocol specified
25/04/2016 10:36:39 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
25/04/2016 10:36:39 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
No protocol specified

25/04/2016 10:36:39 ***************************************
25/04/2016 10:36:39 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
```

so I guess it's related to the run level, but I'm no expert and need some clues to fix it.

Also my `/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/:0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Both `w` or `ps wwwwaux | grep auth` commands tells me the display is still `:0` (which of course makes sense since it works without `sudo`)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I used  -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1566542)(?) in how sddm is doing the authority. You need to replace

```
-auth /var/run/sddm/:0
```

with

```
-auth /var/run/sddm/* -display :0.
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there, it worked using sudo!
...but it didn't fixed my x11vnc.service :(

I read your bugtacker link and looks like yours is the best answer I would get. Anyhow I'm holding the accepted answer mark for if there will be another workaround to fix the auto-start

Comment: Well, I didn't noticed the use of `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c` in the service. Now It's fixed to me as I use a single display. Looks like multiple display users are out of luck.